# Get Array of elements from a chunk of string

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-parsing

I have a template literal with HTML Elements inside, I want to run it through a function and get an Array of all elements with their string.

```
const tmp = `
<div>
 <h1>Heading <span>inline</span></h1>
 <button>Click Me</button>
</div>
`
```

this should give me:

```
["<h1>Heading <span>inline</span></h1>", "<span>inline</span>", "<button>Click Me</button>"]
```

How would I do that?

Comment: So you want the div's innerHTML?

Comment: 1. Parse the HTML, 2. select all elements, 3. get their outer HTML. See [`DOMParser`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), [`querySelectorAll`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [`map`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`outerHTML`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML). What have you tried?

Comment: If you don't have [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) available (in case you're not in a browser environment), you can try [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom)

Comment: I tried DOMParser but I'm struggling to find an API which returns the whole element as string "<div>MyDiv</div>"

Comment: @inux `.outerHTML`? Or [`XMLSerializer`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer)?

Comment: What do you need these strings for?

Comment: @SebastianSimon I would like to discuss only the how I can get this array of elements and not what I will do with that array.

Comment: @inux Just keep in mind that HTML strings may not be the most useful representation. E.g. if you want to insert these HTML fragments somewhere, using the elements directly is much more performant and sensible than intermediately serializing them. Having HTML strings in an array is a weird use case — there’s almost certainly a better approach for whatever you’re trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
const tmp = `
<div>
 <h1>Heading <span>inline</span></h1>
 <button>Click Me</button>
</div>
`
let elems = [],
 domElement = new DOMParser().parseFromString(tmp, "text/xml"),
 results = domElement.evaluate('//div//*', domElement, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

for(let i = 0; i < results.snapshotLength; i++) {
  let node = results.snapshotItem(i); 
  elems.push(node);     
}
console.log(elems)
```

The output should be your expected output.

Comment: `text/html` instead of `text/xml` is probably better. Alternative without XPath: `console.log(Array.from(domElement.querySelector("div").querySelectorAll("*")).map(({ outerHTML }) => outerHTML));`. Also, `domElement` is a misnomer: `domElement` is an `HTMLDocument`, not an `Element`.

Comment: This works perfectly in the browser, I would need a node version of that. Thanks

Comment: @inux - You should probably post the node version request in a separate question, as per SO poilicy.